# Render card layout as 2x2 / 3x3

Tags: css

I am trying to render my cards in 2x2 or 3x3, but currently my cards are only rendered in one row. The styling for my current layout are all defined in style.css.

This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-waterfall-5159n?file=/src/displayItems.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand it right , you can change width in css .column like

for 2*2

```
   .column {
      width: 40%;
    }
```

for 3*3

```
.column {
  width: 30%;
}
```

also you can use Bootstrap col-6 for 2*2 and col-4 for 3*3

Answer (score 0):

add class col-container

```
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="col-container">
        {data.slice(minValue, maxValue).map((item, i) => {
          return i >= minValue && i <= maxValue && createCards(i, item);
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

and setup grid on it.

```
.col-container {
  display: grid;
  width: max-content;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added card-container class

```
 <div className="card-container">
    {data.slice(minValue, maxValue).map((item, i) => {
      return i >= minValue && i <= maxValue && createCards(i, item);
    })}
  </div>
```

You can achieve this 2 / 2 or 3 / 3 using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

```
.card-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem; // add gap between card
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); // Which kind of grid, change 2 to 3 if you want 3 / 3
}
```

More on CSS Grid [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)